# How to represent a variable DC supply potential difference on a circuit diagram

Tags: dc, schematics, variable

I have a circuit diagram for a physics experiment.
On the diagram I have represented a variable DC supply, but I would like to know where do I write the potential difference selected on the variable DC supply.

Comment: Just write it as a note next to the item.

Comment: Generally, I draw it as a single-cell battery with a pointed arrow  drawn through the cell symbol at 45 degree angle: arrow is pointing to top right.  In fact, exactly as in the answer shown by Transistor below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnrpeF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Adjustable voltage annotation.*

There isn't a standard. Either of the above should make it clear to the reader.

If you can define your own symbols you can draw a diagonal arrow (pointing north-east) through the symbol to indicate that it's adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

Normally spec; in footnotes

Vin =Min:Max @ Iin: surge, max.

Vout=Min:Max @ Iout: Peak, max or load regulation error

V dropout or Vin-Vout : depends on buck-boost, buck, or boost or LDO and efficiency

( which may imply Pd max, efficiency and temp rise or cooling requirements.)

More info the better so no one has to guess why their "plasma arc generator" *craps* out the supply or load regulation error causes measurement errors or Notes to add decoupling caps at load to improve transient attenuation @ x Amp step load .....get it?

Or SIMPLY;  **Vadj= X to Y Volts @ Z watts or TBD Amps.**

Then refer to Spec document xyz for PSU specs.